# how to make return element in struct format in C programming

Tags: c

could someone to help me to solve this problem
I have several line code but I got stuck in fuction display where I want to return elems, how I can fix it..I need function and return is as feedback not printf

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "IO.c"

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

void append(struct node** head_ref, int data) 
{ 
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    struct node *current = *head_ref;  
    new_node->data  = data; 
    new_node->next = NULL; 
    if (*head_ref == NULL) 
    { 
        *head_ref = new_node; 
        return; 
    }   
    while (current->next != NULL) 
        current = current->next; 
    current->next = new_node; 
    return;}
 
int display(struct node *head){
    struct node* elems = NULL;
    struct node* current = head;  
    while (current != NULL) 
    { 
        current = current->next; 
        append(&elems,current->data);
    }
    return elems;
}

int main(){
    read_2array_data_file("datauji.dat");
    struct node* tetangga = NULL;
    append(&tetangga, 1);
    append(&tetangga, 2);
    append(&tetangga, 3);
    append(&tetangga, 3);
    display(tetangga);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you provide the remaining elements of a [MCVE] (example input, expected output, observed behavior)?

Comment: I  am sorry before, I will send python code for display function

Comment: What is the `display()` function supposed to do? The name implies it should just print the list, but the code is doing something else.

Comment: def display(self):
  elems= []
  cur_node=self.head
  while cur_node.next!=None:
   cur_node=cur_node.next
   elems.append(cur_node.data)
  return elems
I try imitate the python code to C programming, in python I success to return the function.. but in C programming I am still fail

Comment: Put code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: It seems like `display()` is just making a copy of the list. Why is it called `display()`?

Answer (score 0):

`display()` needs to be declared to return `struct node*` so it can return `elems`. And then you should assign the result to a variable in `main()`.

When you're copying the list in `display`, you need to update `current` *after* you reference `current->data`.

```
struct node *display(struct node *head){
    struct node* elems = NULL;
    struct node* current = head;  
    while (current != NULL) 
    { 
        append(&elems,current->data);
        current = current->next; 
    }
    return elems;
}

int main(){
    read_2array_data_file("datauji.dat");
    struct node* tetangga = NULL;
    append(&tetangga, 1);
    append(&tetangga, 2);
    append(&tetangga, 3);
    append(&tetangga, 3);
    struct node *elements = display(tetangga);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your correction, but I still get error massage,coba.c: In function ‘main’:coba.c:61:26: warning: initialization of ‘struct node *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types],  struct node *elements = display(tetangga);

Comment: You didn't change `int display` to `struct node *display`

Comment: but @Barmar, when I try run y program I get this massage : ./geany_run_script.sh: line 5:  9152 Segmentation fault      "./coba"

Comment: have you try my code on your editor, ? success or not? or you got the same massage

Comment: Found the problem. You were accessing `current->data` after you updated `current = current->next`. That means you dereferenced a null pointer on the last iteration.

Comment: but I have a question,when I run the program  still have problem. I try to run the program or print that with this code                                                               
               for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
  printf("%d \n", *(elements+(i)));
   }

Comment: I got the result is 1 0 2 0 not 1 2 3 4, I dont know what the problem?

Comment: `elements` is not an array, it's a linked list just like `tetangga` is.